# Stop Vue Fireworks animation

Tags: vue.js, html5-canvas

I'm using the vue-fireworks component (https://github.com/dampion/Vue-fireworks) to display an HTML5 Canvas animation of fireworks. It starts when the component is mounted which is fine. But I can't figure out how to make it stop. I need to stop the fireworks after a button click.  I'd prefer that no more fire off and any that are onscreen when the button is clicked are allowed to continue to their conclusion.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: All of the code is from another source. I am trying to find out if anyone else has worked with it and solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to modify the source code of the `Fireworks` component?

I can see that it has a `data prop` of `auto` that is set to `true`.

If you could change that to a straight forward `prop`, then by changing that value to `false` it would stop adding more fireworks and let the other animations finish.

```html
<Firework :boxHeight="'100%'" :boxWidth="'100%'" :auto="false"/>
```

Haven't tested myself, just an assumption reading through the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try changing that value and then reloading so I can confirm it does turn off auto creation. Oddly, it then allows a firework to be shot off each time you click the mouse. I have no idea why you would want that.

Comment: There is an event listener inside the component for clicks. Each time you click it adds a firework. You would have to remove that manually if you don't want it. (it does it event when auto is on)

Comment: Yeah, I think I will remove the click as I don't see a use for it. I did confirm that if you change auto to false while it's running, it just stops creating new fireworks. That's awesome!  Now, I wonder if I should then clear the canvas, stop any further looping and stop it from eating memory or CPU cycles?

Comment: Yes I would recommend doing that. If the answer was what you were after then please consider giving it the green tick 

Comment: Ok, so yes the visual animation stops playing, the fireworks cease to fire. However, the script continue to run in an infinite loop.  I can add a console.log to the start of the loop and watch it keep on looping. Now I need to determine when the last firework bit is done and end the loop.

Comment: You could add a watcher for `seeds`  in the `fireworks` component. Once the `seeds` array has a length of `0` (meaning all fireworks have finished), you `$emit` an event like `animation-complete` and in your parent component, you remove the `fireworks` component completely with `v-if`

Comment: I decided to check for the particles length which seems to work and then I clearRect to reset the canvas.  I like the idea of then just removing it completely.